# How can I stop drag slider

Tags: javascript, slider, draggable

I have a draggable slider, and he moves ok, but he incorrectly stops, at the beginning and at the end of the bar.

```
function drag (handle, event) {
  var diffX = event.clientX - handle.offsetLeft;

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', startDrag, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);

//   START
  function startDrag (e) {
    if (handle.offsetLeft >= 0 && handle.offsetLeft <= 280) {
      handle.style.left = (e.clientX - diffX) + "px";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }

//   STOP
  function stopDrag() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', startDrag, false);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
  }
}
```

Here is the link to full code – http://jsbin.com/ojEWalu/4/edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the handle is at -2px when fully scrolled left.

Your code states `if (>=0)`.

Try

```
if (handle.offsetLeft < 0) {
  handle.style.left = (0) + "px";
}
```